# Clicking on multiple elements in order and if text is present do something

Tags: cypress

I have 4 buttons on the page and if i click them, different data is displayed for each one.

What i want to do is have a method that clicks on button 1 and check if specified text is not displayed on the page, have it click button 2 and so on until the text is displayed. Text is not always displayed on the same button section so i am not able to hardcode this in, i must search for it. If i try to check if element.contains(text) it will give an error as it is not displayed and making if else statements using the contains.size different from 0 will always go to the last else. Any ideas?

Added some sample code of what i have tried. If i can get inside the IF block and stop successfully where the text is displayed, i will make a boolean and using that i can continue with a function

```
cy.get(button1).click()
  cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
    if ($body.find(specifiedText).length > 0) {
      cy.get(elementThatContainsTheText).click()
      // cy.get(specifiedText).click()
    } else {
      cy.get(button2).click()
      if ($body.find(specifiedText).length > 0) {
        cy.get(elementThatContainsTheText).click()
        // cy.get(specifiedText).click()
      } else {
        cy.get(button3).click()
        if ($body.find(specifiedText).length > 0) {
          cy.get(elementThatContainsTheText).click()
          // cy.get(specifiedText).click()
        } else {
          cy.get(button4).click()
          cy.get(elementThatContainsTheText).click()
          // cy.get(specifiedText).click()
        }
      }
    }
  })
  
        cy.get(button1).click()
         cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
     if (cy.get(elementThatContainsTheText).contains("text") > 0) {
       cy.log("text is not here")
     } else {
       cy.get(button2).click()
       if (cy.get(elementThatContainsTheText).contains("text") > 0) {
         cy.log("text is not here button2")
       } else {
         cy.get(button3).click()
         if (cy.get(elementThatContainsTheText).contains("text") > 0) {
           cy.log("i should be here")
         } else {
           cy.log("last else, why am i here?")
         }
       }
     }
     })
```

Comment: Add the code you tried.

Comment: Is the order of the buttons random or the displaying of the text? Seems a bit strange to not know when/where to expect the string.

Comment: the order of the buttons is not an issue as all 4 of them will always be displayed. the issue is that the text is placed depending on what data is received from BE for it. according to that data, the text will be placed in one of the 4 button sections. i cannot control under what button the data will be displayed that is why i would like to click and search on each until it is found.